# Facebook not always sharing links, via Share and Service Links

Tags: facebook, firefox, drupal-6, share

I am having an intermittent problem, when attempting to share some stories
from a Drupal-6 website ([www.legitgov.org](http://www.legitgov.org/)) via the Facebook widget.  While some stories can be
shared, others cannot - the problem seems to be completely random. Here is
more information, to perhaps aid in pinpointing the cause.

1). I have checked for available updates; I appear to be up-to-date on
Modules.

2). The problem occurs with the same links, both on my pc and my Android
phone, using Firefox. The story links I am *able to share* can be shared
on my pc and on my phone. Similarly, those that *cannot be shared* are a
problem w. both the pc and the phone. (I am seeing 'zero' total shares w.
the problematic links, so I am assuming that others, using various
operating systems, cannot share the 'problematic' links, either. The
stories that can be shared seem to be working for all, as I typically see
a high number of shares for the links that work.)

3). All other sharing features (sharing via Twitter, email, etc.) work for
all stories, even those that cannot be shared on Facebook.

4). The error message received, when attempting to share the troubled
links, is: 'This post could not be found.' And yet, the links and posts
themselves are fine.

5). I don't see a pattern with the length of the links that can and cannot
be shared.

On edit:
Here is an image depicting a failed Facebook link share:
http://www.legitgov.org/graphics/fb_share_2.jpg

Thank you,

Lori Price

Comment: Is the length of the links (or there description) to long? There is a max. length for facebook shares.

Comment: Hi, Mainz007. Thank you so much for responding. I didn't see a pattern with link length - some long ones are posting, and some shorter links do not - it's very odd.

Comment: Can you post the url for facebook of an working, and of a non working url pls?

Comment: Here are two screenshots, if that helps. The first depicts a link that is poised to share on Facebook, as proper. The second image shows an 'empty' pop-up box, that will only include a link to the main CLG website, and not to the specific story.

Comment: I see no screenshots...

Comment: Hi, sorry, I can't post an image as I got a message that I have to have 10 for a reputation. Anyway, a link on the site that shares fine is this one: http://www.legitgov.org/Fukushima-has-9-days-prevent-unsafe-overheating. It has, in fact, 7 shares, thus far. This link, for example, will not share: http://www.legitgov.org/least-4-NATO-troops-reported-killed-Afghan-suicide-bombing. Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm using Firefox 30 and I can share both links...

Comment: Hi, I still see a 0 share count for the second link - and the others that I can't share. I am 'too new' to post a screenshot here, can I email it to you? Thanks again for helping me. lori @ legitgov.org

Comment: You can edit your question and post the screenshots there (even when you are new)

Comment: Hi, no, I tried and got this message: 'Your edit couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above.' The error message that appeared said I could not submit images until I hit '10' for reputation.

Comment: Mainz007, here are the links to the uploaded screenshots: http://www.legitgov.org/graphics/fb_share_1.jpg and http://www.legitgov.org/graphics/fb_share_2.jpg Hope that helps.